# iOS development -- check that all UI objects have accessibility label/identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using XCode to build an iOS app. I am currently in the process of defining UI tests using the [framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/) added just last year. In an example test I have:

```
XCUIApplication().segmentedControls["genderSegmentedControl"].buttons["Girl"];
```

The string "genderSegementedControl" is an accessibility label defined by me in its corresponding view controller as:

```
genderSegmentedControl.accessibilityLabel = "genderSegmentedControl";
```

My question is, is there any way of me writing a script, that would check all of my UI objects and verify that they have assigned accessibility label ? I can't seem to find where in Xcode I can view the internals of the story board that I am using. I would love if I could get array of all my objects, and loop through that array and assert that the *.accessibilityLabel* or .*accessibilityIdentifier* property is non nil.

I want this so that I can verify that I have actually included all of my UI components in a test. (Some sort of code coverage if you will.)

Comment: This isn't a full-blown solution but I think it might set you on the right path--> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32105765/4475605

Answer (score 2):

By UI Objects, you probably mean subviews, as every visible element that can be placed in a Storyboard is a subclass of UIView.

In this case, you want to get the **subviews** of the ViewController's View. However, doing so will only return the first level of UIViews, not nested ones. Thus, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243888/how-to-list-out-all-the-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller-in-ios) suggests, you should use a recursive algorithm.

This function should recursively loop through every UIView that is a descendant of the ViewController that this code is written in:

```
func checkSubviews(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view.accessibilityLabel == nil && view.accessibilityIdentifier == nil {
        return false
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if !checkSubviews(view) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Now calling the following function should return false if there are any UIViews (including the view controller's view itself) that lack both an `accessibilityLabel` and a `accessibilityIdentifier`:

```
checkSubviews(self.view)
```